# Set an item on a WPF Combobox when ItemSource is binded to an Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, enums

I am having trouble assigning the a combobox item by using an enum value that the combobox source is assigned to.

The XAML

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                x:Name="cmbName"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="120" Margin="79,48,0,0">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Please Select"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Enum}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

The C# that is trying to set the combobox to an item in the enum

```
// The problem, the assignment doesn't work.

cmbName.SelectedItem =  Enum.value;
```

I can only set a item by using the combobox SelectedIndex

```
cmbName.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

But this is hardcoding the index so if the enum changes, so will the value.

So how can I set the combobox by the enum value?

Thanks

Comment: Post the definition of `StaticResource Enum` please.

Comment: I suspect `StaticResource Enum` is a string enumeration. also wondering why `ListBoxItem` is used in a `ComboBox` instead of `ComboBoxItem`. That is not the reason of the issue but ListBoxItem will be eventually wrapped in a ComboBoxItem so not worth.

Comment: Thanks @pushpraj for spotting the ListBoxItem. Changed it to a ComboBoxItem. Quickly, how do you highlight words as code in the comments box as you have done?

Comment: @user3428422 wrap the word to highlight in ` marks and SO will do the rest, see [Markdown Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more formatting options

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to tell what your problem is because you haven't fully documented your scenario. As such, all that I can do is to show you how to do what you want. As I prefer to work with properties, I won't be using any `Resource`s for this example, but I'm sure that you'll still be able to relate this solution to your problem.

So, first we have a test `enum` and some properties and some initialisation:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    None, One, Two, Three
}

private TestEnum enumInstance = TestEnum.None;
public TestEnum EnumInstance
{
    get { return enumInstance; }
    set { enumInstance = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("EnumInstance"); }
}

private ObservableCollection<TestEnum> enumCollection = new ObservableCollection<TestEnum>() { TestEnum.None, TestEnum.One, TestEnum.Two, TestEnum.Three };
public ObservableCollection<TestEnum> EnumCollection
{
    get { return enumCollection; }
    set { enumCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("EnumCollection"); }
}
```

...

```
EnumCollection.Add(TestEnum.One);
EnumCollection.Add(TestEnum.Two);
EnumCollection.Add(TestEnum.Three);
EnumInstance = TestEnum.Three;
```

Then we have a `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding EnumCollection}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding EnumInstance}" />
```

If you run the application, then at this point the selected `ComboBoxItem` should read `Three`. Because the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` is data bound to the `EnumInstance` property, setting...:

```
EnumInstance = TestEnum.Two;
```

... is roughly the same as:

```
ComboBox.SelectedItem = TestEnum.Two;
```

Both of these would select the `Two` value in the `ComboBox`. However, note this example:

```
EnumInstance = TestEnum.None;
```

Setting either the `EnumInstance` or the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property to `TestEnum.None` would have no effect in the UI because there is no `TestEnum.None` value in the data bound collection.

Comment: Totally agree with this, so I have voted it up, however, and its my fault for not including it, I cannot use a property as stated above. I'd advise coders to being this method.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise that my answer was descriptive enough, however, the reason why I haven't set my enum as a property as Sheridan has described below is that I need an extra string value in my combo which you can see is "Please Select" and unfortunately, I cannot put this in the enum.

But Sheridan's method and logic is the way to go if you want to do this.

However, for my problem, I simply just used

```
ComboBox.SelectedValue = Enum.Value.ToString();
```

Thanks

Comment: so `StaticResource Enum` is a collection of string values of enum.

Comment: @pushpraj I dont think so, as I don't use a converter to return a string. I set the resource as

           <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetNames" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">

Comment: mate, please edit the first post with this additional info or raise another question.